# Table view with bottom corner like the iPad Notes app

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm doing something which looks like the list of notes of the iPad Notes app: a classic table view, but with a corner at the bottom, like this:

[image]

So in order to view the bottom of the list, the scroll view is kind of special.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to set a footer height for your last section using the heightForFooterInSection.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section==[mySections count]) {
    return 120;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!
To change the default footer view use:
`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
 view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 return view;
}`